# Adding images to datatable jquery plugin

Tags: datatables, tabletools

I am using the following datatable plugin:
[datatables](http://datatables.net/index)
And using the following to export data from the datatable
[Table tools](http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/)

I need to have images in some cells of the datatable. The way I am inserting the image is that I am giving in the html for that cell.

But when I export the data. The cells containing images come as empty strings. Is it possible to get the image url in the csv that is exported?